# Java compilers or JVM languages that support goto?

Tags: java, programming-languages, language-design

Is there a java compiler flag that allows me to use `goto` as a valid construct? If not, are there any third-party java compilers that supports `goto`? If not, are there any other languages that support `goto` while at the same time can easily call methods written in Java?

The reason is I'm making a language that is implemented in Java. Gotos are an important part of my language; I want to be able to compile it to native or JVM bytecode, although it has to be able to easily use Java libraries (ie. C supports `goto`, but to use it I'd have to rewrite the libraries in C).

I want to generate C or Java, etc source files, and not bytecode or machine code. I'm using a third-party compiler to do that.

Comment: Plan B: Download the OpenJDK, and hack up the Java compiler in it to support goto. :-P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JVM support goto at bytecode level.
If you are doing your own language, you should use libraries like [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), not generating .java file.

Answer (score 5):

The JVM bytecode contains a goto instruction (e.g. see the [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/manual.html) documentation).

Don't forget that Java itself supports the concept of jumping to labels, using:

```
break {labelname}
```

or

```
continue {labelname}
```

See this [JDC tech tip](http://java.sun.com/developer/TechTips/2000/tt0613.html) for more info. If your language is compiled to JVM bytecode, then you may be able to make use of this.

Comment: syntax is without the brackets:

    break labelname;

Comment: Yes. I was putting {labelname} to indicate some label should be inserted there. Perhaps not very clear, I appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, no Java compiler allows goto.  Java compilers must implement the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/), and the JLS does not allow gotos.  However, it is also clearly possible to compile a language with gotos to the JVM.  [AMPC](http://freshmeat.net/projects/ampc) is one C-to-JVM compiler that claims to support C89.

Also note that Java bytecode has a goto instruction, though it's obviously instruction-based not line-based.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code generator to target [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/). You can use goto in Jasmin as much as you like. :-)

Comment: Targeting Jasmin is about equivalent to targeting ASM/BCEL (as in J-16's answer), so meh. :-P

Answer (score 1):

The `goto` keyword is reserved but unused in the Java programming language. (From [Section 3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.9) of [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/j3TOC.html).)

Therefore, at least in the Java programming language, there is no way to enable the use of `goto`.

However, as already noted, the [`goto` opcode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Instructions2.doc5.html) in the Java virtual machine is functional, and used when the Java compiler produces bytecode from the source.

[Chapter 7: Compiling for the Java Virtual Machine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Compiling.doc.html) from [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) may be of interest when implementing a JVM language.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much anything you can do with goto you can do with a loop. goto is really redundant and generally discredited way to program. IMHO.

If you want to goto backwards

```
LABEL: do {
// code before goto

// goto LABEL
continue LABEL;

// code after goto
break;
} while(true);
```

If you want to goto forwards

```
LABEL: do {
// code before goto

// goto LABEL
continue LABEL;

// code after goto
break;
} while(false);
// Label is effectively here
// code after LABEL.
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow using `goto` keyword. However, it allows using labels and using `break` or `continue` with label instead of `goto`. In facts, Java is not a language without goto statement, but a language with uncomfortable implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Thrift can be used to generate source code in different programming languages from a single source. http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't, ever, use goto, as it's EVIL ;-)

More seriously, maybe you could have a look at the famous article from E. Dijkstra :
http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Comment: "You should not do this." Is not an answer to the question, "How can I do this?"