# Programming in Java bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm looking to write a short program (maybe a Hello World) in Java bytecode. I just want to write the bytecode using my text editor and run it. How would I do this? Got an example? Thanks!

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html and use `printf` in bash :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could try [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/)!

```
.class public HelloWorld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  .limit stack 3
  .limit locals 1

  getstatic      java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  ldc            "Hello World."
  invokevirtual  java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

  return

.end method
```

You compile it using:

```
> java -jar jasmin.jar hello.j
```

And then you run it like any class:

```
> java HelloWorld
Hello World.
```

**Update**

I see that your question mentions "without using Javac or Java". Could you clarify how you meant that statement?

Comment: This post makes me want to fake the work I'm doing today and tinker around with Jasmin. :-)

Comment: +1 Jasmin is what came to my mind and I couldn't remember the name. It was featured in a book that explains JVM internals. I Forget the name of the book too, *sigh*...

Comment: @Bakkal: According to the link: "Jasmin was originally created as a companion to the book "Java Virtual Machine", written by Jon Meyer and Troy Downing and published by O'Reilly Associates."

Comment: by "without using Javac or Java," I just meant that I want to write the code using bytecode. Thanks for the info!

Comment: wow~ This is super cool. is this JVM independent as well? can this run on a blackberry jvm?

Comment: @Viele: Yes, this should be JVM independent (so long as the JVM you're interested in conforms to the JVM specification).

Comment: @Corey, how is this different from using a plan `.java` file and `javac` ?

Comment: Wow!! I've been working for a while on bytecode. Why haven't I heard of this?

Comment: Jasmin is ok for ordinary use, but it doesn't support a lot of the more obscure things you can do in classfiles. If you want a heavy duty assembler see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

I've created a new [Java bytecode assembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) that is backwards compatible with Jasmin but also adds lots of new features and simplifies the syntax slightly.

Here's an example of how you might write a Hello World program.

```
.class public hello
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static main : ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit stack 10
    .limit locals 10

    getstatic java/lang/System out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ldc "Hello World!"
    invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    return
.end method
```

[I've also written a tutorial on bytecode assembly](https://greyhat.gatech.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Java_Assembly_Tutorial). It currently only covers Hello, World, but I can continue it if there is interest.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Sorry about that. It looks like the whole wiki is gone. I'll email them to see if they can bring it back or have any copies.

Answer (score 9):

Byte code is written as actual bytes, which are not normally easily editable by a normal text editor.

This means you will need something that converts a textual representation to binary.  A reasonable place to start would be an assembler like [Jasmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmin_%28Java_assembler%29).