# Is it possible that write a program with Java bytecode instructions directly?

Tags: java

In .NET platform it is possible to write a program with Common Intermediate Language directly and compile the sources with IL Assembler (ILASM).

For example below code is "Hello World" program.

```
.assembly Hello {}
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.method static void Main()
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    ldstr "Hello, world!"
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    ret
}
```

Is it possible that write a program with Java bytecode instructions directly like .NET?

Comment: There is asm (http://asm.ow2.org/) for that.

Comment: Not an answer to your question (which is yes, but not simple ;)) here's a nice blog post with references http://arhipov.blogspot.se/2011/01/java-bytecode-fundamentals.html?m=1

Comment: Why would anyone want or need to do this? Since it's a stack based machine I doubt there are any tricks you could do that the compiler doesn't already know about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check out Jasmin. From Wikipedia,

> Some projects provide Java assemblers to enable writing Java bytecode by hand. Assembly code may be also generated by machine, for example by compiler targeting Java virtual machine. Notable Java assemblers include:
>
> [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/), takes textual descriptions for Java classes, written in a simple assembly-like syntax using Java Virtual Machine instruction set and generates a Java class file.
>
> Jamaica, a macro assembly language for the Java virtual machine. Java syntax is used for class or interface definition. Method bodies are specified using bytecode instructions.

Note: I've not used any of these tools personally.

Comment: Can these tools be used to embed inlined JVM instructions in normal Java sourcecode?

Comment: @Philipp - I've never heard of a version of javac that would allow inlined "assembler" language.  (I'm also not sure how well/easily Jasmin works since the loop annotation massacre.)

Answer (score 7):

You could use Jasmin

```
 .class public HelloWorld
 .super java/lang/Object

 .method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
 .limit stack 3
 .limit locals 1

  getstatic      java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  ldc            "Hello World."
  invokevirtual  java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

 return

.end method
```

You compile it using:

> java -jar jasmin.jar hello.j

You could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150254/programming-in-java-bytecode) also