# creating a loop in java?

Tags: java, loops

I have been struggling to figure out how to make my code loop when asking for user input.

Basically, I want the program to re-ask the question if the user enters no text at all.
This is what I done so far.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

  public class Assessment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

          BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

          String me = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
          System.out.println("Your name is: " + me);

          String user1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose a number");
          System.out.println("Your number is: " + user1);

          String user2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your choice of    security, choice1(low) or choice2(high)");
          String response = (String)System.in.toString();

          if(user2.equals("choice1"))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your username is: "+me+user1,"Your username",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);


    }
}
```

Comment: Search for do while structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need to do -

```
   String me = "";

          do
          {   
            me = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
          }while(me.equals(""));
```

Do it for your other windows too.

Or, just copy paste this code :(

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Assessment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));

        String me = "";
        String user1 = "";
        String user2 = "";

        do {
            me = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
        } while (me.equals(""));

        System.out.println("Your name is: " + me);

        do {
            user1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose a number");
        } while (user1.equals(""));
        System.out.println("Your number is: " + user1);

        do {
            user2 = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Please enter your choice of    security, choice1(low) or choice2(high)");

        } while (user2.equals(""));
        String response = (String) System.in.toString();

        if (user2.equals("choice1"))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your username is: " + me
                    + user1, "Your username", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

Comment: @user3063011 -  great. you need to learn more things. btw, please choose my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!me.equals("")) {

}
```

to compare `Strings` in Java you have to use **equals()** and since you don't want it to be equal to empty text you should use the negation in Java.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop that refers to what they entered:
like while input = ""{question} or even a do while loop.
See this question:
[Goto statements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547662/goto-statements-in-java)

This may also help:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Answer (score 0):

use java.util.Scanner.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

After prompting for the name, use the following:

```
String name = input_next();
if (name != null && !("").equals(name)) {  //then move next - else go back to the prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a great tutorial on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), specifically the "while" and "do-while" statements.

In short :

```
while (condition) { 
   // statements
}
```

and

```
do {
   // statements
} while (condition);
```

As long as the condition evaluates to true, the statements will keep getting executed. The difference between while and do-while is the time at which the conditions are evaluated, refer to the tutorial for more information.