# Java multi-level break

Tags: java, loops, break, multi-level

I have a construct where I have a `for` loop nested inside of a `while` loop in Java. Is there a way to call a `break` statement such that it exits both the `for` loop and the `while` loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java/2545160#2545160 there you go :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a 'labeled' break for this.

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] arrayOfInts = { { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
                            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
                            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
                          };
    int searchfor = 12;

    int i;
    int j = 0;
    boolean foundIt = false;

search:
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                foundIt = true;
                break search;
            }
        }
    }

    if (foundIt) {
        System.out.println("Found " + searchfor +
                           " at " + i + ", " + j);
    } else {
        System.out.println(searchfor
                           + " not in the array");
    }
}
```

}

Taken from:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in 3 ways:

- You can have while and for loops inside method, and then just call `return`
- You can break for-loop and set some flag which will cause exit in while-loop
- Use label (example below)

This is example for 3rd way (with label):

```
 public void someMethod() {
     // ...
     search:
     for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
             if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                 foundIt = true;
                 break search;
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

example from [this site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

In my opinion 1st and 2nd solution is elegant. Some programmers don't like labels.

Answer (score 2):

[Labelled Breaks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

For example:

```
out:
    while(someCondition) {
        for(int i = 0; i < someInteger; i++) {
            if (someOtherCondition)
                break out;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the loop be inside a function call and return from the function?

Answer (score 1):

You should able to use a label for the outer loop (while in this case)

So something like

```
    label:
        While()
        {
          for()
          {
             break label;
          }
        }
```