# This odd Java code compiles without errors

Tags: java, compilation

Here is an interesting piece of code I came across:
It looks quite strange but it does compile.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    http://servername:port/index.html
    System.out.println("Hello strange world");
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This was asked `n` times already. `http:` is a label...

Comment: And the `//` is a comment, making the rest ignored.

Comment: nice. I liked that so much.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. And Yep. this appear to be a dupe. thanks tomato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A label followed by an inline coment

Yes, Java has label

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    hello:
}
```

And of course online comments

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i; // this is a comment.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### `http:` is a label. The rest is just an inline comment `//`.

One can ask, why do we have labels in Java?

First thought: `goto`. But, `goto` implementation has been removed from Java as needless. The only thing which stayed is a reserved keyword `goto`. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)

So, what's the usage of labels?

Labels can be used with `break` statement. Example from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), with `search` label:

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

    search:
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`http:` is a label

`//servername:port/index.html` is a comment.