# Why are there keywords in Java that have no usage, yet are reserved?

Tags: java, keyword

I tried to do a quick search about this, but nothing specifically answering my question came up. As you might know there are keywords reserved in Java that don't do anything.

- const
- goto

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Complete answer here: [Java Language Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). Only `const` and `goto` are currently reserved but not used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java

Comment: BTW `false`, `true` and `null` are not keywords.

Comment: Presumably the authors of Java thought that A) they might want to use them in the future, and B) having variables named "const" and "goto" could be very confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These words are keywords in many other languages, and it could be confusing if they were used as identifiers.

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java#answer-4547764), apparently the original JVM did have `goto` which was removed later.