# Java Eclipse: Skip lines (NOT IN DEBUGGING)

Tags: java, eclipse

In Java code, is there a way to have the program "skip" lines of code (NOT during debugging)?
ex:

```
if ( userInput.equals("one") ){
   Skip to line 82
} else {
continue to next line
```

Comment: You would use functions for this

Comment: How? (I apologize I'M switching form JavaScript to Java

Comment: How would Java have to do that? If on line 83 a method is declared, like, for example, `public void test() {` and line 84 contains `doSomething();`, then line 84 cannot be reached without passing line 83.

Comment: By all that is sacred and profane do not implement `goto` in Java.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how would I use a function to skip lines depending on what happens in the code before the function?

Comment: Yes, write methods, write branching code with `if` or `switch` statements.

Comment: AAHHHH makes sense! Thanks for giving me the lightbulb MadProgrammer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most languages, this `Skip` feature is implemented as `goto`.

Java made the concious decision not to include this in its language because it can enable bad code.

See

[Is there a goto statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)

You can always comment over lines, but you made it clear its not for debugging purposes.

Instead, use `if`

```
      if(condition){<whatever you would have had between here and 82>}.
```

If `condition` evaluates to `false`, the lines will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the condition with its logical negative, and move everything between the "next line" and line 82 (in your example) into the block.

```
if(!userInput.equals("one")) {
    //Next lines, up to your old line 81.
}
//Line 82.
```