# I was reading a post and someones comment confused me.

Tags: java, break

OK, so I was looking up the goto statement in java, and I stumbled on this post:
[Is there a goto statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)
(I know, I'm a scrub :P )

Anyways, I stumbled across this chuck of code in the comments:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

 boolean t = true;

 first: 
 {
    second: 
    {
       third: 
       {
           System.out.println("Before the break");

           if (t) {
              break second;
           }

           System.out.println("Not executed");

       }

       System.out.println("Not executed - end of second block");

    }

    System.out.println("End of third block");

 }
}
```

And I am confused as to why the second block wouldn't have been executed after the break. Can someone explain this to me?

I would've commented to ask, but I don't have a high enough Rep to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: "*And I am confused as to why the second block wouldn't have been executed after the break.*" I am confused about your confusion. That is kind of whole point of `break second;`, to break code block labelled with `second` (to move flow of control right after this block). What other behaviour did you expect?

Comment: I misunderstood the usage of break then, I thought it was to break away from where you are in the code, then start at the specified label.

Comment: @AustenClay you confused break with goto.

Comment: @zubergu, I realize that now :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I am confused as to why the second block wouldn't have been
>   executed after the break.

Because the `break` statement with label terminates the labeled block and does not take the execution back to the label.