# How to convert a comparative if statement to a switch case statement?

Tags: java

I'm new to java programming and I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Here's my code:

```
boolean running = true;
   PANTS:
while (running) {
    int waistMeasure = in.nextInt();

    if (waistMeasure >= 26 && waistMeasure < 28){
        System.out.println("You are a Small.");
        break;
    }
    if (waistMeasure >= 28 && waistMeasure < 30){
        System.out.println("You are a Medium.");
        break;
    }
    if (waistMeasure >= 30 && waistMeasure <= 34){
        System.out.println("You are a Large.");
        break;
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to convert this into switch case statements?

Comment: So 28 is medium or large?

Comment: Actually, it's supposed to be 30 to 34. That's a mistake on my part.

Comment: @shmosel Medium of course. ;-) `break` prevents reaching next `if` statement.

Comment: You can edit the post.

Comment: @Nighthawk, so [fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37664519/edit).

Comment: you should omit `else` in the current state of your code

Comment: @Alnitak it does when this code is within a for-loop, but that leaves us guessing and therefore a bad MVC example.

Comment: @Alnitak did you miss the `while` loop?

Comment: @martijnn2008 ah yes, I forgot about the outer loop!

Comment: is `PANTS:` a label? You are not using a `GoTo` are you? http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966

Comment: @martijnn2008 Yes, it's a label. No, there is no `goto` shown. Label can be used to correctly break loop if using `switch`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37664706/5221149).

Comment: @martijnn2008 Java [doesn't have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2545141/3529323) `goto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is – but you’d have to create a `case` for each value (as shown below). You cannot express a range of values with a single `case`. So if you want readable and maintainable code, you should stick with `if`s.

```
switch (waistMeasure) {
case 26:
case 27:
    System.out.println("You are a Small.");
    running = false;
    break;
case 28:
case 29:
// ....
}
```

Comment: `break` won't exit the loop anymore.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the comment; setting `running` to `false` solves this problem.

Comment: I see.  I was hoping there would be a way to execute a specific range of values with a single case statement, but apparently Java can't do something like that.

Comment: @Nighthawk Correct, it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (waistMeasure) {
    case 26:
    case 27:
        System.out.println("You are a Small.");
        break PANTS;
    case 28:
    case 29:
        System.out.println("You are a Medium.");
        break PANTS;
    case 30:
    case 31:
    case 32:
    case 33:
    case 34:
        System.out.println("You are a Large.");
        break PANTS;
    default
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: `break` won't exit the loop anymore. Need to `break PANTS` like [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37664706/5221149). *LOL "break pants"*

Comment: I guess an `if` statement isn't that bad after all...

Comment: @Andreas, good point. I was wondering why the label was there...

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

Notice that you have to use the `PANTS` label for the `break` statement to exit the loop, otherwise they just break from the `switch` and will continue looping.

```
PANTS: for (;;) {
    int waistMeasure = in.nextInt();
    switch (waistMeasure) {
        case 26:
        case 27:
            System.out.println("You are a Small.");
            break PANTS;
        case 28:
        case 29:
            System.out.println("You are a Medium.");
            break PANTS;
        case 30:
        case 31:
        case 32:
        case 33:
        case 34:
            System.out.println("You are a Large.");
            break PANTS;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Someone don't like break on label? I find it more clear than using boolean flag to control loop, especially if loop is large (cannot be seen in full on screen without scrolling).