# what does the statement means in Java?

Tags: java

I find a strange statement while reading the openjdk resources.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElYbv.png)

what does the "found:{}" means?

Comment: check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: Terrible title.  Reds to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

`found:{}` is a label in Java mainly used for `goto` statement but since Java doesn't use `goto` it can be used for `break` and `continue` statement. Here is an example of using a label in Java.

```
    loop: 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            if(j==5)
            {
                break loop;
            }
            System.out.println(j);
        }

    }
```

When `j` reach 5 it will trigger break to outside `loop` label.

Comment: *"mainly used for goto statement"* Java doesn't have a `goto` statement. See: [Is there a goto statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2545103/5221149)