# How to use the goto statement in Android

Tags: java, android

How can I use `goto` in Android?

Comment: "goto" who told you it is supported...if you know java then you might be knowing that it is not supported in java itself....;-).....

Comment: @reno is it an OS? i thought it is software stack....

Comment: I don't see how this is "not a real question". How to use a goto statements in Android might be asking the wrong question, but there still is an answer, and it's potentially useful for other people who mix up Android and Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tha language used in [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) is [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), and there isn't any `goto` by itself in Java.

You can use a labeled `break` or other alternatives as described in [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Alternative to a goto statement in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java/2430829), but these constructs should be avoided as long as possible, as they produce really ugly and hard-to-maintain code.

Just figure out how to design your code correctly, and you will never need `goto` and such stuff ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) in Java you cannot use a goto statement. Java does not provide a goto statement in its grammar.