# Jumping from one method to another using goto statement

Tags: c#, java

Can i use **goto statement** to jump from one method into another in c++ , java or c#.

Comment: @ShashankKadne: That is incorrect, C++ does not support `goto` jumping between methods.

Comment: @GregHewgill: I can't even label a method and then call goto to jump to that label??....i never tried it!

Comment: @ShashankKadne - no you can't.  Try it.  The compiler won't let you.  And in the Java case, `goto` is not supported because the designers thought it was a bad language feature, not because of any real or imaginary security concerns.

Comment: Thanks folks...that means my comment makes no sense. I should better remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with java. `goto` is a reserved word (statement) but it is not useable by design.

Further reading:

- [Is there a goto statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)
- [Alternative to a goto statement in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java)

Comment: Interesting. Had no idea about `goto` in java being just wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Not in C#. It is possible to jump inside *one* method though.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 goto statement is used to jump some where inside the same method.