# Syntax error on token goto throw expected

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a goto statement in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)

In my android application i used goto statement to control the flow. But I received error as "Syntax error on token goto, throw expected". Here is my code

```
label:
if(alc)
{
  r_code=st.nextToken();
  AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(Fetch.this);
  alert.setTitle(count+" records found for "+rytname.getText().toString());
  alert.setMessage("Are you sure want to search for "+r_code+"?");
  alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      ff=1;
      alc=false;
    }
  });

  alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      ff=0;
   }
  });
  alert.show();
  if (ff==0)
  {
    goto label;
}
```

I'm new to this android, and help me to avoid this error

Comment: Ok, But how to avoid this error?

Comment: There is no *goto* in Java. It is a reserved-word, but is unused.

Comment: people still using `goto` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
label:
...// the rest of your code
if (ff == 0) 
{
    goto label;
}
```

Use this:

```
do {
...// the rest of your code
while (ff == 0);
```

Even better if you can convert it to:

```
while (ff == 0) {
...// the rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**There is no working `goto` in Java**

Even though the Java keyword list [specifies the goto keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), it is marked as *not used*. Hence, it cannot work. You have to rewrite your code without using the `goto` keyword.

A general hint: there are [Labeled Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

> Statements may have label prefixes.
>
> ```
> LabeledStatement:
>      Identifier : Statement
>
> LabeledStatementNoShortIf:
>      Identifier : StatementNoShortIf
> ```
>
> The Identifier is declared to be the label of the immediately contained Statement.
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement;
>   identifier statement labels are used with [break (§14.15)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15) or [continue
>   (§14.16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.
>
> The scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately
>   contained Statement. – JLS (§14.7)

But what you really want, is to rewrite your constructs without using that, for instance by using `while`

```
while (f == 0) {
     // ...
}
```

Comment: What do you meant by not used?

Comment: It does nothing. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2545141/759019)

Comment: Possibly refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7

Answer (score -2):

It is not advised to use `goto` in the code since it will be unclear from readability point of view. Instead of `goto`, one can use `break` and `continue`. Alternative for `goto` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java/2430829)