# How can I go to line which I want on Android?

Tags: android, goto

I'm choosing random questions and answers. And I want to generate new question and answers again after users chose the right answer. How can I do that without for loop? Is there a code like "go to"?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use goto type statements if you have constructed your code correctly in Java/Android. You can achieve something similar with break and continue statements. This post explains how to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java

Answer (score 0):

"Goto" loops are generally frowned upon - consider using a while-loop maybe?