# How to go back to a specific line in Java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, labeled-statements

I'm writing code that involves an if-else statement asking the user if they want to continue. I have no idea how to do this in Java. Is there like a label I can use for this?

This is kind of what I'm looking for:

```
--label of some sort--
System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y/N");
if (answer=='Y')
{
    goto suchandsuch;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: call suchandsuch method. if the condition is true.

Comment: Please go thorough these posts: 

1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java

Comment: I would use a while loop and break unless the user decides to continue.  It is very unusual to use goto for any programming these days as most loop constructs and/or function-based programming are better for each specific situation a goto might be used in.

Comment: `goto` has its place (though its place is fairly limited). Obviously, its place doesn't include languages that don't support it :-)

Answer (score 9):

Java has no `goto` statement (although the `goto` keyword is among the reserved words). The only way in Java to go back in code is using loops. When you wish to exit the loop, use `break`; to go back to the loop's header, use `continue`.

```
while (true) {
    // Do something useful here...
    ...
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y/N");
    // Get input here.
    if (answer=='Y') {
        continue;
    } else {
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a +1 just for NOT using the `goto` statement!

Comment: After you prompt the user if they want to continue, couldn't you just do `if(answer != 'Y') break;` ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Java gives me no such option (to be sure, I'm quite happy about it, too :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Off my head, there are known as "labels" - but I'd just forget they exist ;)

Comment: @JoshM Right, this is definitely sub-optimal. I just wanted an opportunity to show both `continue` and `break` in a single snippet, so I changed the OP's code as little as possible to get it done.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think labeled `break`s are nice, because they let you break out of multiple nested loops - the only semi-legitimate case for having `goto` that I've heard.