# How to jump in java

Tags: java

I have a code like this

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        continue s;
        System.out.println("I am not supposed to print this");
        s:
        System.out.println("I am suppose to print this");

    }
}
```

I get the error

```
java: undefined label: s
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Java does not support `GOTO` (and similar). And frankly, I think `GOTO` makes code confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, there is no practical way to do that in Java.  You appear to be trying to do the equivalent of a "goto", and that is not supported in Java.  The `break label` and `continue label` statements can only branch to an *enclosing* labelled statement.

Now according to the Java formal grammar you could write this:

```
  s: {
      continue s;
      System.out.println("I am not supposed to print this");
  }
  System.out.println("I am suppose to print this");
```

but that *still* won't compile for two reasons:

- The continue is only allowed to branch to a label on a loop statement.  (A `break` doesn't have that restriction ... but ...)
- The `continue` (or a `break`) makes the next statement unreachable.

See also: [Alternative to a goto statement in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java/2430829#2430829)

---

But there is one rather tricky way to get your code to "work":

```
  static final boolean flag = true;  // class attribute ...

  ...

  s: {
      if (flag) break s;
      System.out.println("I am not supposed to print this");
  }
  System.out.println("I am suppose to print this");
```

The "test" there will be evaluated by the compiler so that the `break` is effectively unconditional.  But the JLS says that the first `println` will be *treated as* reachable, so that you won't get an unreachable code error.

I guess this *might* be useful if you are *generating* this source code.  Apart from that, it is (IMO) just a curiosity.  It is simpler to do this with a regular `if` /  `else` statement ... or by deleting the first "print" entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Jumping like this is not possible in Java, only way to jump is from loops, while and do.

- [What is the "continue" keyword and how does it work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/continue-keyword-in-java)

Read [@Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545155/516167) answer

> **2.2.6 No More Goto Statements**
>
> **Java has no goto statement**. Studies illustrated that goto is (mis)used more often than not simply "because it's there". **Eliminating goto led to a simplification of the language**--there are no rules about the effects of a goto into the middle of a for statement, for example. Studies on approximately 100,000 lines of C code determined that roughly 90 percent of the goto statements were used purely to obtain the effect of breaking out of nested loops. As mentioned above, multi-level break and continue remove most of the need for goto statements.
>
> [The Java Language Environment, James Gosling
> and Henry McGilton, 1996](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/simple-142616.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "goto" in java. And "continue" does a little bit other function. You can use "continue" for example in loops like:

```
class ContinueDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String searchMe = "peter piper picked a " + "peck of pickled peppers";
        int max = searchMe.length();
        int numPs = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            // interested only in p's
            if (searchMe.charAt(i) != 'p')
                continue;

            // process p's
            numPs++;
        }
        System.out.println("Found " + numPs + " p's in the string.");
    }
}
```

In the example above, if for example `searchMe.charAt(5) != 'p'` then the loop will continue from the beginning of loop from i=6, and `numPs++;` will not be processed.

You can read more about this here:
[Branching Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 0):

**continue** is a keyword in Java used to **skip iterations of a loop.**
If you are trying to find an equivalent to **GOTO**, you should **reconsidering** how you are trying to solve your problem, **GOTO is never a valid option, ever.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no goto in Java (there is a keyword, but it has no meaning)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, Java have Jump statements `return` and `break`.

The `return` statement jumps out of a method, with or without returning values to the calling statement.

The `break` statement jumps out of loops.

As mentioned in the earlier answers, `goto` is not available in Java, and is not considered to be a good programming practice in procedural or object oriented programming. It existed back in the days of sequential programming.