# About labels in Java behaving like GOTOs

Tags: java, goto

Shouldn't this loop infinitely?

```
someLabel:{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i == 3)
                break someLabel;
        }
}
```

It goes

```
0
1
2
3
```

Then dies. I was reading a question about an alternative to GOTO in Java. This was the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430789/555690. Shouldn't the for loop be executed again?

Comment: You're breaking _from_ the labeled block.

Comment: that `break` will "break" the code block, it is not like a `continue` inside a for/while loop

Comment: Read the language ref.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html:

> The break statement terminates the labeled statement; it does not transfer the flow of control to the label. Control flow is transferred to the statement immediately following the labeled (terminated) statement.

Apart from the fact that I never saw any real code using this kind of control flow, I guess a use for it would be to break an outer loop from an inner loop (as described in the provided link):

```
search:
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
             j++) {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                foundIt = true;
                break search;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15) states

> A `break` statement **with label *Identifier*** attempts to transfer control
>   to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) **that has the same
>   *Identifier* as its label**; **this statement, which is called the break
>   target, then immediately completes normally.**

The statement here is actually a block statement. Once you `break`, that block ends.

So, no, the `for` loop should not iterate again since it's inside the block that just ended.