# How to return to a specific line of code in java

Tags: java, repeat

OK so this is my first post here. (Be kind to me :)) I'm like two weeks old to java and wanted to create an app that can do the jobs of a total, average and average grader.
My question here is. How can I return to a specific line of code after one operation has ended
Eg: I want the code to runString menu1="Input the number of the operation you desire "; after the total or average has been found.
Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class grader
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Input your Chemistry marks");
    float a= input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println ("Input your Biology marks");
    float b= input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println ("Input your Physics marks");
    float c= input.nextFloat();

    String menu1="Input the number of the operation you desire ";
    String op1="1. Total ";
    String op2="2. Average ";
    String op3="3. Grade ";
    String op4="4. Exit ";
    System.out.println (menu1+op1+op2+op3+op4);

    Scanner menuselect=new Scanner(System.in);
    int option= input.nextInt();

            float tot=(a+b+c);
            float avg=((a+b+c)/3);
    if (option==1)
        System.out.println ("Your total is "+tot);

    else if (option==2)
        System.out.println ("Your average is "+avg);

    else if (option==3)
        if (avg<0.0)
            System.out.println ("Please input proper data");
        else if (avg<=49.9)
            System.out.println ("Fail");
        else if (avg<=69.9)
            System.out.println ("Pass");
        else if (avg<=100.0)
            System.out.println ("Excellent");
        else 
            System.out.println ("Please input proper data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it all in a ``while`` loop?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `do-while` loop. How it works is it executes some code, checks to see if a condition evaluates to `true`, and if so, executes the code again.

```
do {
    //your code here
}
while (/*some condition*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you want to repeat one or more lines of code, you do so using a loop. In general, a loop is set up like this:

```
while(loopGuard){

    //code to repeat

}
```

Where `loopGuard` is some boolean statement that gets updated inside your loop. The code inside the loop will continue executing until your `loopGuard` statement is no longer true.

In your case, you may want to loop until the user presses a certain button, until it has run a certain number of times, or any other arbitrary reason you have chosen. The main thing to remember is to make sure that your loop guard will eventually become false, otherwise you'll find yourself in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use a `while` loop with the usage of `continue` and `break`. A second option, you can use a labeled `break` statement (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-a-goto-statement-in-java)).

Btw, in java language there a `goto` keyword. But it's not implemented (or removed). Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a do - while loop . A do while loop runs at least once , which is necessary as you're program needs to be run at least once . Put all the statements from Input the operation number to the calculating statements under do while loop . It should work out just fine .

Comment: This solution is already posted by other answerers. Clarify what additional value ad your post is giving