# how to use goto in java

Tags: java, arraylist, goto

```
StartAgain:
    if(nit_arr.size() > 2)
    {
        System.out.println("size of list is more than 2");
        j = prev.size()-2; 
        k = prev.size()-3; 
        if(nit_arr.get(j) == myChoice && nit_arr.get(k) == myChoice){
            //System.out.println("Last 2 selections of nitish are same so next one should not be");
            myChoice = (int )(Math.random() * 2);
            goto StartAgain;
        }
    }
```

i want to regenerate a random number if last last two elements in the array lists are same and
 the list is having more than 2 elements in it. its not a loop to use break/continue. so how can i achieve this?

Comment: How any don't, instead stucfure your code to work without it using loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to a goto statement in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-a-goto-statement-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

It's a horrible design decision, but you can use [lableled statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) in Java. In your case, you *might* use

```
continue StartAgain;
```

But you really should redesign your method. The JLS link for 14.7 says (in part),

> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no `goto` statement; identifier statement labels are used with `break` ([§14.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)) or `continue` ([§14.16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16)) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

Comment: i tried this but i got "continue can not be used out of a loop" error?

Comment: What version of Java? Also, no version of Java has a `goto`.

Comment: java versoin 1.8.0_51

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(bool again = nit_arr.size() > 2; again;)
    {
        System.out.println("size of list is more than 2");
        j = prev.size()-2; 
        k = prev.size()-3; 
        if(nit_arr.get(j) == myChoice && nit_arr.get(k) == myChoice){
            //System.out.println("Last 2 selections of nitish are same so next one should not be");
            myChoice = (int )(Math.random() * 2);
        }
        else{
             again = false;
             // do other stuff if needed
        }
    }
```

This is how we can achieve it, as well as most other constructions, without the need for a goto statement. Goto is usualy not recommended even in C/C++, because it breaks the structure of the code and makes it more difficult to track (by a human). Sure, everything in the compiled version will be translated into gotos, jumps, etc.

Another way using break; slightly less recommended but ok:

```
    while(nit_arr.size() > 2)
    {
        System.out.println("size of list is more than 2");
        j = prev.size()-2; 
        k = prev.size()-3; 
        if(nit_arr.get(j) == myChoice && nit_arr.get(k) == myChoice){
            //System.out.println("Last 2 selections of nitish are same so next one should not be");
            myChoice = (int )(Math.random() * 2);
        }
        else break;
    }
```