# the meaning goto _L1

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recompile decompiled Java (JD / JAD) source that contains goto instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036984/recompile-decompiled-java-jd-jad-source-that-contains-goto-instructions)

what's the meaning of    goto _L1 when i decompile class java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036984/recompile-decompiled-java-jd-jad-source-that-contains-goto-instructions

Comment: i guess it transfers the control to the mentioned label, but why do you care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decompiler was not wise enough to handle some statements, most likely compiled try-catch-statements. So he resigns, and does something syntactically correct, but unlikely to be like this is the original source.

```
goto _L1
```

is just a Java statement meaning go to the instruction AFTER the block of code following the goto statement (This is mad, I know, but that is how Java implemented it).

Comment: how can i replace goto to eliminate the error

Comment: Open editor, write something else. Use different decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

`goto` isn't a Java keyword. What you're seeing is a remnant of improper decompilation.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: Strictly speaking `goto` **is** a keyword in Java. It just has no meaning.

Comment: Well, the code never compiles if there's a `goto`. Quoting Sun, "The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used." it is a reserved keyword.